# Cannot access OpenSSH server outside LAN

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I installed OpenSSH server on my router in order to perform remote maintenance and access an external drive through SFTP.

When I'm connected to LAN, everything works fine and I can access the router through both its local and external IP address, but trying to accessing it elsewhere gives 'Connection Refused' error. Port configuration shouldn't be the problem, I used a port scanner to verify that the port I specified is indeed open.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs of the OpenSSH server? There may be lines in there that tell you why it was refused.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem a firewall/routing problem, you have verified that access to port 22 is not limited to the LAN ip range only ?

Comment: I agree - it may be that the default (or current) setting of the OpenSSH server is to allow LAN connections only. However, this means that it shouldn't work if connecting using the external address, despite being inside the LAN as it will still go through the ISP - effectively connecting to it externally...

Comment: @QuickishFM, the fact that you connect to external address doesn't mean the connection leaves the router, goes to ISP and circles back. Router will notice its own IP address and terminate location locally.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is different to some implementations that I have personally experienced, so I assumed as such. Thanks for clarification - i think this further supports the fact that either some ports are not forwarded correctly or the openSSH server itself declines connections from external addresses.